# kotlin - run vs elvis operator - what is the difference?

Tags: kotlin

im trying to understand the difference between the following two pieces of code in kotlin:

```
myVar?.let { print(it) } ?: run { print("its null folks") }
```

vs

```
myVar?.let { print(it) } ?:  print("its null folks")
```

are they equivalent ?  is run just so we can use a block of code and the the other is for just a single statement ?

Comment: maybe it's an obvious consideration, but `run` returns the result of the code block you're supplying, so it must return the same type as the left side of the elvis operator

Comment: so other then providing a block to write code, the ?: run{}    and ?:   are the same right

Comment: to me yes, I don't see any difference. Moreover, you could do the same even without `run`, by simply creating and executing a lambda (e.g., `x ?: { doSomething(); doSomethingElse() }()`), which is more or less what `run` does

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. `run` allows you to use multiple statements on the right side of an elvis operator; in this case there's only one, so `run` is not needed.